# Closed subscheme of smooth scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to better understand the situation of smooth schemes. Suppose we have a smooth affine integral $k$-scheme of finite type $X$, and let $k$ be algebraically closed (hence 'smooth' is equivalent to 'regular'). Now let $f_1, \dots, f_n \in \mathcal O_X(X)$ be a regular sequence and we also suppose that the closed subscheme $V(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ is smooth. Does it hold that for any $1 \leq i \leq n$ the closed subscheme $V(f_1, \dots, f_i)$ is smooth as well?

Thank you very much for any hints!

Comment: This is in general false.

Comment: What is true is that $V(f_1,\dots,f_i)$ is smooth along $V(f_1,\dots,f_n)$.

Comment: Dear @Sasha, thank you for the comment. I think this is because if $Y = V(f_1, \dots, f_i)$ and $Z = V(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ and $y \in Y \cap Z$, then we have an isomorphism $\kappa(y) = \mathcal O_{Y,y}/\mathfrak m_{Y,y} \cong \mathcal O_{Z,y}/\mathfrak m_{Z,y}$, and thus the Jacobian matrix of $f_1, \dots, f_i$ has rank $i$ at all points in $\kappa(y)$, because $Z$ is smooth.

Comment: @johnnycrab: Right!

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks again!